Where can I find the calculations of the 4th-order corrections ${\cal O}(e^4)$ for the anomalous magnetic dipole moment?
I am looking for the calculations of the 4th-order corrections to the magnetic dipole moment of the electron.
The 2nd-order corrections ${\cal O}(e^2)$ are solved by Feynman in his original paper to get the answer $\frac{1}{2}$. They are relatively straight forward and don't require renormalisation. Only tricky bit really is simplifying the gamma matrices using identities and using Feynman's method of combining factors in the denominator. From Feynman's original paper he does it much more straight forwardly than is described in other modern papers.
The 4th-order corrections have been calculated to be:
$$\frac{197}{144} + \left(1-6 \ln 2\right)\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac{3}{4}\zeta(3)$$
from the diagrams shown in fig.4. I believe in this case it does require renormalisation or regularisation since some of the diagrams contain internal fermion loops. Though I'm not 100% sure. I don't think any of the steps are particularly complicated but the number of terms doubles with each additional fermion line since it has the factor with two terms: $(m+\not k)$.
That is why I'd like to examine the calculations myself. But I can't find the detailed calculations anywhere only the results. In fact I found this paper saying that some of the calculations have never been published.
Can you recommend any papers, books or Mathematica notebooks which have the detailed calculations of the fourth order corrections? So that I can follow along and have a go at doing the calculations myself?

You could always try contacting the authors of the papers themselves....these calculations tend to be in house built methods of calculation. You definitely aren't likely to find a mathematica book that contains this.

@Triatticus I might try that. I wonder why the calculations are not already published on the internet somewhere though. This stuff was calculated 60 years ago. Modern computers should be able to do the calculations in seconds. That is another problem, some of the original authors might not even be alive now.

SHELL2: a package for the calculation of two-loop on-shell Feynman diagrams in FORM “As an example of an application the two-loop coefficient for the anomalous magnetic moment of the electron in QED is reproduced in the framework of dimensional regularization.”

It's surprisingly hard to find detailed calculations of these two-loop effects in the literature. Back in the 1950s, when such calculations were first done, journal space was highly limited and mathematical typography was difficult, so papers tended to be very short. They were essentially sparse descriptions of final results, with the details discussed in person at seminars and conferences. And people made mistakes all the time! These days people are computing five loop effects, using elaborate computer programs which can get the two loop result in a millisecond, but the two loop result isn't novel so it isn't regarded as worth publishing.
So, as Consa says in the paper you linked, and more emphatically in this later paper, there are no research papers which give a complete and correct derivation of the two-loop result. Unfortunately, this has recently led to claims, within podcasts and YouTube channels, that the two-loop result doesn't exist. Many listeners now believe that physicists are engaged in a massive conspiracy, where we simply pretend to calculate loop corrections, but in reality just make up random numbers. Of course, nothing could be further from the truth. I know some people involved in precision calculations, and they're extremely concerned about reproducibility. They really do have computer programs that can output the answers, and they constantly check that independently written programs give consistent answers.
A few months ago, I had the exact same question as you, so I asked one of these people for a pedagogical reference. After some digging, he suggested I look at

On the two loop calculation of the anomalous magnetic moment of the electron (1992)

This is a short (~10 page) note which was based on a talk at a summer school, where PhD students are trained in their specialties. It outlines an efficient method to calculate the two-loop contribution, based on a recursion relation which can easily be evaluated by a computer. It gives explicit expressions for every Feynman diagram, including the one that Consa claims is "missing".
I have personally corresponded with Consa on this point, though he stopped responding once I brought up this paper.
Following a comment above, if you want a ready-made program, you can also download ON-SHELL2, a code for the symbolic manipulation system FORM.

Thank you for the link. BTW I'm not one of the people who believe the result doesn't exist, but I do like to check calculations for myself since I think this is essential in science. Also I think this is just a "fun" thing to try and calculate using computer algebra etc.

Who or what is Consa?

@bmargulies Author of the paper OP linked, and originator of the claim that quantum electrodynamics is a massive fraud perpetuated by generations of physicists.

Yes there should be repository where calculations are detailed, if only so that groups can benchmark their codes against known results, and I sympathize with Consa for this, but h*ll no this does not imply a massive conspiracy.   How ridiculous can you get?

@ZeroTheHero You can find anything on "mindblowing" YouTube. By my estimation of viewcounts, the majority of people who heard anything about QED in the past year did so via one of those videos.

incredible… nothing else to say…
